# Ejercicio raiz cuadrada recursiva en C++

Tags: c++, recursión

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de sacar la raiz cuadrada de forma recursiva por aproximaciones. Por ejemplo para la raiz cuadrada de 2 ,empezaria en 1, luego en 1.5, 1.25, 1.375 asi hasta que la encuentre pero no consigo realizar correctamente la funcion recursiva.

```
float calcularRaiz(double raiz, double aux, double aux2) {


    if (aux*aux==raiz) {

        return aux;

    }

    else {

        if (aux * aux > raiz) {



        }

        cout << aux << endl;

        return calcularRaiz(raiz, (aux + aux2) / 2, aux);

    }



}
```

Por ahora tengo esto pero no consigo que me realice todas las aproximaciones hasta llegar a la solucion ya que se queda en un bucle infinito.

double raiz seria en este caso un 2, aux seria raiz/2 y aux2 seria la raiz(2).

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En donde tu funcion estaria buscando una aproximacion?? estas buscando la raiz exacta.. en realidad esto funciona, pero no vas a encontrar la exacta de muchos numeros...

Answer (score 2):

Una forma simple pero poco eficiente de hacerlo, sería como la que sigue:

```
#include<iostream>

double calcular_raiz(double,double);

int main()
{
    double valor = 16; //Número al que le quieres calcular la raíz cuadrada
    double aux = 1;

    std::cout << "La raiz cuadrada de " << valor << " es: " << calcular_raiz(valor,aux);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

double calcular_raiz(double valor, double aux)
{
    if(aux*aux==valor) return aux;
    else
    {
        if(aux*aux>valor) return calcular_raiz(valor,aux/2);
        else return calcular_raiz(valor,aux+1);
    }
}
```

Esta fue una solución que se me ocurrió cuando recién comenzaba con ejercicios de recursión, pero resalto lo defectuoso del código de la siguiente forma: este código **sólo sirve para calcular raíces cuadradas de números cuadrados perfectos** (1, 4, 9, 16, 25...), o para calcular raíces cuadradas de **algunos** números sin decimales infinitos (0.5, 0.5625...); ya que si queremos calcular la raíz cuadrada de 3 (cuya solución es irracional), la computadora se queda en un bucle infinito del que nunca va a salir, y el costo computacional de este código es alto.

Más adelante aprendí que existen métodos numéricos para aproximaciones rigurosas que son muy efectivos. Te dejo un enlace a un blog donde se trata este tema y se brinda un código bien explicado utilizando el método de Newton-Raphson [aquí](https://gist.github.com/Haylin-chama/6179118).

Si estás interesado en leer más acerca de los métodos numéricos y sus aplicaciones, te recomiendo el libro ***"Métodos numéricos para ingenieros"***, *quinta edición*, de *Steven C. Chapra*.

¡Espero que haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: que es lo que faltaria para hacer raices de cuadrados no perfectos?

Comment: En el enlace que te dejé se analiza un método numérico para el cálculo de raíces cuadradas de cualquier número (perfectos o no perfectos) con una gran precisión. Ese código funciona de maravilla; si lo copias y lo pegas y luego lo pruebas con cualquier número verás que te lo resuelve muy bien. Te adjunto una página con más información sobre otros métodos numéricos y con enlaces a videos/tutoriales que hablan del tema: http://maralboran.org/wikipedia/index.php/Ra%C3%ADces. ¡Un saludo!